# run a script to fill in a model

Tags: django

I have a script that fills a model (a table) with data. To run the script I do `python manage.py shell < script.py` it worked correctly several times but there it no longer fills the table I don't know why.

```
import names
from app.models import Employee, Sector
from random import randint

s1 = Sector.objects.create(namesector="marketing", codesector="MKT"); s1.save()
print("start of the loop")
for i in range(10):
       n = names.get_full_name().split(" ")
       print(n[0] + " " + n[1])
       p = Employee.objects.create_user(firstname=n[0], name=n[1], regID=str(i).zfill(2), codesector="MKT", password=str(i).zfill(2))
       p.save()
print("end of the loop")
```

Only s1 is added to the Sector table, the employee table remains empty.
When i write line by line directly in the shell the data is added correctly for the employee table.

---

```
(.env) λ python manage.py shell < quiz/script/fillTable.py
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> --- start of the loop ---
>>> ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... Bertha Lucchese
David Berardi
... # I did not put the rest of the names
Esteban Albers
>>> --- end of the loop ---
>>>
now exiting InteractiveConsole...
```

Comment: Print n0 and n1 in the loop, do you get the right data? You are asking something with minimal info, can only guess.

Comment: @saro hello i added print (i edit my post) and now the table employee is contains data, i don't understand lol .